# Are strings in C++ copied when modified?

Tags: c++, string

Using the std::string class in C++, it is possible to modify a character using the array notation, like:

```
std::string s = "Hello";
s[0] = 'X';
cout << s << '\n';
```

I have checked that this code compiles, and prints "Xello" as expected. However, I was wondering what the cost of this operation is: is it constant time, or is it O(n) because the string is copied?

Comment: It is constant, you are modifying the buffer directly. Actually copying whole string under cx11 should be O(n) as it uses move semantics.

Comment: in C++11, `s` has its copy of the string from the moment it is constructed. C++03 allows *copy on write*, so it depends on the implementation.

Comment: There is no copying involved with this code whatsoever. We only have an initialization and an assignment.

Comment: I asked because if I wanted to do the same thing in Java, since strings are immutable, the only way would be to copy the string in O(n) time with the required change, iirc.

Comment: @H2CO3 the individual `char`s of `"Hello"` are always copied at some point in this code, in any version of C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify stl string like in you example, no copy will be done. Standard library string class does not manage string pool like other languages do for strings (like Java). This operation is constant in complexity.

Answer (score 1):

The string isn't copied. The internal data is directly modified.

It basically gets the internal data pointer of the actual string memory, and modifies it. Imagine doing this:

```
char *data = &str[0];
for(size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
{
   data[i] = '!';
}
```

The code sets every character of the string to an exclamation mark.
But if the string was copied, then after the first write, the data pointer would become invalid.

Or to use another example:
   std::cout << str[5] << std::endl;

That prints the 6th character of the string. Why would that *copy* the string?
C++ can't tell the difference between `char c = str[5]` and `str[5] = c` (except as far as const vs non-const function calls go).

Also, str[n] is guaranteed to never throw exceptions, as long as n < str.size(). It can't make that guarantee if it had to allocate memory internally for a copy - because the allocation could fail and throw.

(As @juanchopanza mentioned, older C++ standards permitted CoW strings, but the latest C++ standard forbids this)

Comment: This should be the selected answer because it provides an example and evidence.

Answer (score 0):

You do only modify the first element `s[0]`, therefore it can't be O(n). You don't copy the string.

Comment: Faulty logic. On a COW implementation (now disallowed), changing a single element causes Copy On Write (by definition), and that copy definitely is O(n).